# ml divide function in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm quite new to MATLAB, and I was wandering the following question: if A is a square, non-singular matrix, b a vector of the same length, if I ask Matlab to do A\b (so, the function mldivide) the answer will be calculated in the most efficient way (or, at least, in a decent way: without doing the inverse, for example), or it will roughly do inv(A)*b?

Comment: This sounds like a question that's more appropriate for [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). That said, Matlab does calculate `A\b` in an efficient way. In fact, if you write `inv(A)*b` in a script, it will warn you that this is probably not the most efficient way to do things.

Comment: thank you, I will try there